# TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, type found, functions

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to write a program which uses functions to open a file and then use the lines in the file to play a card game, but I keep getting this error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/ecunning/Documents/Treasure Hunt Game Lab", line 115, in
>   
>       drawCard()   File "/home/ecunning/Documents/Treasure Hunt Game Lab", line 102, in drawCard
>       deck = readDeck(file)   File "/home/ecunning/Documents/Treasure Hunt Game Lab", line 26, in readDeck
>       infile = open(fileName , 'r') TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, type found

Here is my Code:

```
def getfileName():
    fileName = raw_input("What is the name of the file?: ")
    return fileName

    while (fileName != fileDescription):
        print("Invalid file name.  Select an appropriate file: ")
        fileName = raw_input("What is the name of the file?: ")
        return fileName

def readDeck(fileName):
    infile = open(fileName , 'r')
    deck = []

    for card in infile:
        print card  
    return deck

def getCardType(deck):
    cardType = input("What is the location of the card would you like to extract from the deck: ")
    card = deck[cardType]
    return card
    print card

    while (cardType > len(deck)):
        print "This location is not in the deck.  Re-enter a location that is within the list"
        cardType = input("What is the location of the card would you like to extract from the deck: ")
        card = deck[cardType]
        return card
        print card

    newDeck = deck.remove(str(card))

    cardGroup = card[:1]
    return cardGroup
    print cardGroup

    if str(cardGroup) == ruby:
        print "This card is a ruby"
    elif str(cardGroup) == emerald:
        print "This card is an emerald"
    elif str(cardGroup) == coal:
        print "This card is coal"
    else: 
        print "This card is a diamond" 


def getCardValue(card):
    cardValue = card[2:]
    cardAmount = int(cardValue)
    return cardAmount

def displayList(card):
    drawnCards = []
    drawnCards.append(card)
    drawnCards.sort()
    print ("List of drawn cards: ") ,drawnCards.sort()

def getPosition():
    cardType = input("What is the location of the card would you like to extract from the deck: ")
    card = newDeck[cardType]
    return card
    print card

    while (cardType > len(deck)):
        print "This location is not in the deck.  Re-enter a location that is within the list"
        cardType = input("What is the location of the card would you like to extract from the deck: ")
        card = deck[cardType]
        return card
        print card

def drawCard():
    cardtotal = 0
    while (cardtotal < winValue): 
        getfileName()
        deck = readDeck(file)
        cardType = getCardType(deck)
        if (str(cardGroup) != coal):
            cardtotal = cardtotal + cardAmount
            print cardtotal
            getCardValue(card)
            displayList(card)
            cardType = getPosition()
        else:
                print "You drew a coal card.  The game is over"
    print "You have drawn 21 points! You win!"

drawCard()
```

Any help would be great!! Thanks.

Comment: You have multiple issues, the current one being   `deck = readDeck(file)` you are passing `file` which is a python class/type, it should I imagine be `readDeck( getfileName())` . Your while loop after `return fileName` is not reachable and you seem to be accessing  multiple undefined variables

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are passing in a `function` object instead of a `string` object on that line. I'd imagine what you are trying to do is call that method like this:

```
deck = readDeck(getfileName())
```

You also seem to have numerous issues with variable scope and control flow in your program, so I recommend you [read up on](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) [your problems](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) and then go through your program and fix all the issues you see